# Можно ли упростить этот скрипт?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Есть скрипт, выводит простые числа:

```
$simple = array();

for ($iii = 2; $iii <= 20; $iii++) { 
    $flag = true;
      for ($jjj = 2; $jjj <= $iii/2; $jjj++) {
        if( $iii % $jjj == 0)
            $flag = false;
  }
    if($flag==true)
        $simple[] = $iii; 
}  
var_dump($simple);
```

Не пойму итерации по этому циклу **for**, почему именно при **$iii/2** скрипт отработает и выведет натуральные числа в массиве.

```
for ($jjj = 2; $jjj <= $iii/2; $jjj++)
```

Было бы хорошо, если бы поэтапно пояснили..Спасибо.

Comment: разве, что $iii && $jjj можно сократить до $i && $j

Comment: эт понятно, но вопрос не в этом)

Comment: похоже на поиск простых чисел... тут почитайте, со сравнением скорости выполнения. https://habrahabr.ru/post/122538/

Comment: уже смотрел это. Там сложнее ещё и там не php

Answer (score 6):

Что можно сделать, чтобы этот код стал лучше:

1. Использовать адекватные имена переменных.
2. Использовать постоянный стиль кодирования.
3. Выкинуть лишний `if`
4. Задокументировать не очевидное условие цикла прямо в коде.

<sub>Вам может показаться, что это мелочи, но с точки зрения читаемости и дальнейшей поддержки кода это **очень важные** мелочи.</sub>

С учетом вышесказанного, ваш код может иметь вид:

```
$prime = array();

for ($num = 2; $num <= 20; $num++) {
    // Обратите внимание на условие цикла:
    //       div <= (num / 2)
    // Это условие позволяет исключить из перебора значения div, которые заведомо дают
    //       num % div != 0
    for ($div = 2; $div <= $num / 2; $div++) {
        if($num % $div == 0) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $prime[] = $num;
}

var_dump($prime);
```

---

Теперь несколько слов об условии:

```
div <= (num / 2),      (1)
```

Докажем утверждение о том, что в интервале

```
(num / 2) < div,       (2)
```

нет ни одного `div`, такого, что:

```
(num % div) == 0,      (3)
```

Преобразовав выражение (2) получим:

```
2 > (num / div),       (4)
```

Иными словами

```
(num / div) ∈ (0, 2),  (5)
```

Единственным значением (`num/div`), удовлетворяющим условие (3) из этого интервала является 1 (что означает равенство `num` и `div`). Таким образом, в интервале:

```
(num / 2) < div
```

нет ни одного `div`, такого, что

```
num % div == 0
```

**UPD:**

В комментариях верно отмечают, что условие вложенного цикла можно заменить на:

```
div <= sqrt(num)
```

О том, почему это допустимо при поиске простых чисел, читайте в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5811151/2674819).

Comment: Плюс, что это вас на стиль кодирования потянуло?

Comment: @Naumov, в смысле? Я никогда не говорил, что стиль кодирования не важен. Ну и раз уж вопрос, фактически, про код-ревью, то нужно показать максимально качественный код в ответе

Comment: стоит наверное все-таки условие изменить с деления на 2 на квадратный корень, если это действительно простые числа

Comment: @Grundy, возможно. Но мне жаль еще полчаса времени на доказательство адекватности такой замены :) К тому же ТС еще и разжевать его код просит

Comment: @Grundy, добавил замечание о квадратном корне

Comment: Плюс, но еще можно вынести проверку числа на простое в функцию, и использовать вместо внутреннего явного цикла isPrime, тогда код становиться более читабельным :)

Comment: @Sven Есть еще два простых варианта упростить поиск, но усложнить код: 1. Перебирать в какчестве кандидатов на делитель только 2 и нечетные числа (вместо `$div++` написать `$div = ($div + 1) | 0x01`; 2. Перебирать только простые числа из диапазона [2, sqrt($num)]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $simple = array();
>
> for ($iii = 2; $iii <= 20; $iii++) { 
>     $flag = true;
>       for ($jjj = 2; $jjj <= $iii/2; $jjj++) {
>         if( $iii % $jjj == 0)
>             $flag = false;
>   }
>     if($flag==true)
>         $simple[] = $iii; 
> }  
> var_dump($simple);
> ```

Во-первых, отформатировать нормально и переименовать переменные:

```
$prime = array();

for ($i = 2; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
  $flag = true;

  for ($j = 2; $j <= $i/2; $j++)
    if ($i % $j == 0)
      $flag = false;

  if($flag == true)
    $prime[] = $i; 
}

var_dump($prime);
```

Дальше выкинуть флаг, заменить `$j <= $i/2` на `$j*$j <= $i`:

http://ideone.com/c0Wldf

```
$prime = array();

for ($i = 2; $i <= 20; $i++)
{
  for ($j = 2; $j*$j <= $i; $j++)
    if ($i % $j == 0)
      continue 2;

  $prime[] = $i; 
}

var_dump($prime);
```

Проверку на простоту можно было бы вынести в функцию, тогда не понадобится `continue 2`.

---

Ну и если чисел надо проверять много, то стоит задуматься о решете Эратосфена.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, исправил на `$j*$j <= $i`. Перепутал переменные))